# How to make useEffect react on props change as fast as ComponentDidUpdate?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

rotateLogo() fires immediately when isLoading prop gets updated in the following case:

```
class Logo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      };
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
      if (this.props.isLoading) {
        this.rotateLogo();
      }

    }

...
```

However, when trying to implement the same in a functional component with useEffect, there is a considerable delay between the update of isLoading and 
the activation of rotateLogo()

```
const Logo = ({ isLoading }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoading) {
      rotateLogo();
    }
  }, [isLoading])

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking to synchronously re-render in this case so you should use `useLayoutEffect` instead of `useEffect`: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect